# Calico Node and Kube Proxy crashed permanently on a new node

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, ubuntu-22.04, calico

I have a Kubernetes cluster in version 1.25.0 with some nodes (Ubuntu server machines). I use calico from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/projectcalico/calico/v3.26.1/manifests/calico.yaml.
Now I am adding a new node. The node is completely identical. The only exception is that it has a 2.5gbit network port instead of a 1gbit network port.
On this node, both calico node and kube proxy crash permanently. On all other nodes it works fine. Calico Node reports the following as the reason for the crash:

```
Readiness probe failed: calico/node is not ready: BIRD is not ready: Error querying BIRD: unable to connect to BIRDv4 socket: dial unix /var/run/calico/bird.ctl: connect: connection refused W0724 00:54:46.157624 73 feature_gate.go:241] Setting GA feature gate ServiceInternalTrafficPolicy=true. It will be removed in a future release.
Back-off restarting failed container
```

Kube proxy just crashes with `back-off restarting failed container`.

The logs of all look good, no errors - not even warning. Here is a part of the logs from the calico node container:

```
2023-07-24 01:35:34.609 [INFO][115] felix/int_dataplane.go 1893: Received interface update msg=&intdataplane.ifaceStateUpdate{Name:"calico_tmp_B", State:"", Index:76}
2023-07-24 01:35:34.609 [INFO][115] felix/int_dataplane.go 1913: Received interface addresses update msg=&intdataplane.ifaceAddrsUpdate{Name:"calico_tmp_B", Addrs:set.Set[string](nil)}
2023-07-24 01:35:34.609 [INFO][115] felix/hostip_mgr.go 84: Interface addrs changed. update=&intdataplane.ifaceAddrsUpdate{Name:"calico_tmp_B", Addrs:set.Set[string](nil)}
2023-07-24 01:35:34.609 [INFO][115] felix/int_dataplane.go 1893: Received interface update msg=&intdataplane.ifaceStateUpdate{Name:"calico_tmp_A", State:"", Index:77}
2023-07-24 01:35:34.609 [INFO][115] felix/int_dataplane.go 1913: Received interface addresses update msg=&intdataplane.ifaceAddrsUpdate{Name:"calico_tmp_A", Addrs:set.Set[string](nil)}
2023-07-24 01:35:34.609 [INFO][115] felix/hostip_mgr.go 84: Interface addrs changed. update=&intdataplane.ifaceAddrsUpdate{Name:"calico_tmp_A", Addrs:set.Set[string](nil)}
2023-07-24 01:35:34.609 [INFO][115] felix/int_dataplane.go 1803: Dataplane updates throttled
2023-07-24 01:35:35.603 [INFO][115] felix/int_dataplane.go 1770: Dataplane updates no longer throttled
bird: device1: Initializing
bird: direct1: Initializing
bird: device1: Starting
bird: device1: Initializing
bird: direct1: Initializing
bird: Mesh_192_168_178_58: Initializing
bird: Mesh_192_168_178_25: Initializing
bird: Mesh_192_168_178_70: Initializing
bird: Mesh_192_168_178_38: Initializing
bird: Mesh_192_168_178_72: Initializing
bird: device1: Starting
bird: device1: Connected to table master
bird: bird: device1: Connected to table masterdevice1: State changed to feed
bird: device1: State changed to feed
bird: direct1: Starting
bird: direct1: Connected to table master
bird: direct1: State changed to feed
bird: direct1: Startingbird: 
Graceful restart started
bird: bird: direct1: Connected to table masterGraceful restart done
bird: direct1: State changed to feedbird: 
Startedbird: 
Mesh_192_168_178_58: Starting
bird: bird: Mesh_192_168_178_58: State changed to startdevice1: State changed to up
bird: Mesh_192_168_178_25: Starting
bird: Mesh_192_168_178_25: State changed to start
bird: Mesh_192_168_178_70: Starting
bird: Mesh_192_168_178_70: State changed to start
bird: Mesh_192_168_178_38: Starting
bird: bird: direct1: State changed to upMesh_192_168_178_38: State changed to start
bird: Mesh_192_168_178_72: Starting
bird: Mesh_192_168_178_72: State changed to start
bird: Graceful restart started
bird: Started
bird: device1: State changed to up
bird: direct1: State changed to up
bird: Mesh_192_168_178_58: Connected to table master
bird: Mesh_192_168_178_58: State changed to wait
bird: Mesh_192_168_178_25: Connected to table master
bird: Mesh_192_168_178_25: State changed to wait
bird: Mesh_192_168_178_72: Connected to table master
bird: Mesh_192_168_178_72: State changed to wait
bird: Mesh_192_168_178_70: Connected to table master
bird: Mesh_192_168_178_70: State changed to wait
bird: Mesh_192_168_178_38: Connected to table master
bird: Mesh_192_168_178_38: State changed to wait
bird: Graceful restart done
bird: Mesh_192_168_178_58: State changed to feed
bird: Mesh_192_168_178_25: State changed to feed
bird: Mesh_192_168_178_70: State changed to feed
bird: Mesh_192_168_178_38: State changed to feed
bird: Mesh_192_168_178_72: State changed to feed
bird: Mesh_192_168_178_58: State changed to up
bird: Mesh_192_168_178_25: State changed to up
bird: Mesh_192_168_178_70: State changed to up
bird: Mesh_192_168_178_38: State changed to up
bird: Mesh_192_168_178_72: State changed to up
2023-07-24 01:35:41.982 [INFO][115] felix/health.go 336: Overall health status changed: live=true ready=true
+---------------------------+---------+----------------+-----------------+--------+
|         COMPONENT         | TIMEOUT |    LIVENESS    |    READINESS    | DETAIL |
+---------------------------+---------+----------------+-----------------+--------+
| CalculationGraph          | 30s     | reporting live | reporting ready |        |
| FelixStartup              | -       | reporting live | reporting ready |        |
| InternalDataplaneMainLoop | 1m30s   | reporting live | reporting ready |        |
+---------------------------+---------+----------------+-----------------+--------+
2023-07-24 01:36:27.256 [INFO][115] felix/int_dataplane.go 1836: Received *proto.HostMetadataV4V6Update update from calculation graph msg=hostname:"storage-controller" ipv4_addr:"192.168.178.72/24" labels:<key:"beta.kubernetes.io/arch" value:"amd64" > labels:<key:"beta.kubernetes.io/os" value:"linux" > labels:<key:"kubernetes.io/arch" value:"amd64" > labels:<key:"kubernetes.io/hostname" value:"storage-controller" > labels:<key:"kubernetes.io/os" value:"linux" > labels:<key:"specialServerType" value:"storage" > 
2023-07-24 01:36:29.551 [INFO][115] felix/int_dataplane.go 1836: Received *proto.HostMetadataV4V6Update update from calculation graph msg=hostname:"node1" ipv4_addr:"192.168.178.25/24" labels:<key:"beta.kubernetes.io/arch" value:"amd64" > labels:<key:"beta.kubernetes.io/os" value:"linux" > labels:<key:"kubernetes.io/arch" value:"amd64" > labels:<key:"kubernetes.io/hostname" value:"node1" > labels:<key:"kubernetes.io/os" value:"linux" > labels:<key:"node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane" value:"" > labels:<key:"node.kubernetes.io/exclude-from-external-load-balancers" value:"" > 
2023-07-24 01:36:34.389 [INFO][117] monitor-addresses/autodetection_methods.go 103: Using autodetected IPv4 address on interface enp11s0: 192.168.178.88/24
2023-07-24 01:36:37.850 [INFO][115] felix/summary.go 100: Summarising 20 dataplane reconciliation loops over 1m3.5s: avg=13ms longest=180ms (resync-filter-v4,resync-ipsets-v4,resync-mangle-v4,resync-nat-v4,resync-raw-v4,resync-routes-v4,resync-routes-v4,resync-rules-v4,update-filter-v4,update-ipsets-4,update-mangle-v4,update-nat-v4,update-raw-v4)
```

I absolutely don't understand this. I have already rebuilt the whole node, updated calico node and also tried other kubernetes versions (1.25.11). No firewall is installed. Can anyone help me here? Thanks

PS:
I have already tried all autodetection methods. Right now I use IP_AUTODETECTION_METHOD=can-reach=8.8.8.8

Output of ifconfig on the node:

```
 ifconfig -a
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:50:db:52:31  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp11s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.178.88  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.178.255
        inet6 fe80::67c:16ff:fec8:53e6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2a02:908:523:bd80:67c:16ff:fec8:53e6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 04:7c:16:c8:53:e6  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 8748  bytes 6634723 (6.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 242  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 6342  bytes 944277 (944.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 390  bytes 47600 (47.6 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 390  bytes 47600 (47.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

tunl0: flags=193<UP,RUNNING,NOARP>  mtu 1480
        inet 192.168.53.192  netmask 255.255.255.255
        tunnel   txqueuelen 1000  (IPIP Tunnel)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 39  bytes 13183 (13.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp12s0: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 60:e9:aa:5e:01:95  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find and fix the problem myself. I have always installed all nodes with this guide:

https://www.edureka.co/blog/install-kubernetes-on-ubuntu

This seems to be outdated and does not set important kernel parameters.
After using this guide, Calico now starts normally:

https://www.linuxtechi.com/install-kubernetes-on-ubuntu-22-04/

Specifically, if I am not mistaken, it is about this command:

```bash
sudo tee /etc/sysctl.d/kubernetes.conf <<EOF
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 1
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 1
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

**Error: BIRD is not ready: Error querying BIRD: unable to connect to BIRDv4 socket: dial unix /var/run/calico/bird.ctl**

The above error is caused mainly when you are having multiple interfaces and your calico plugin is not able to detect the correct interface, because of a misconfiguration in setting the interface or IP address. The common fixes are either assigning static IP addresses or to enable [auto detection of interfaces.](https://docs.tigera.io/archive/v3.1/reference/node/configuration#ip-autodetection-methods)

Below  are few additional references for the same:

1. https://github.com/projectcalico/calico/issues/2834#issuecomment-528400727
2. https://github.com/projectcalico/calico/issues/2042#issuecomment-419655823

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work, I have already used all autodetection methods. I have added the output of ifconfig above.

Comment: @TaminoElgert have you tried by giving multiple interface names as mentioned [here](https://github.com/projectcalico/calico/issues/2042#issuecomment-635120190)

Comment: Yes, I have tried that too. Does not work

Comment: The node also has the correct IP address stored in Kubernetes. The Ip address of the node is always static 192.168.178.88

Comment: @TaminoElgert can you check whether the same ip is being used by any other node or machine and also check whether the calico pods are in crashloopbackoff state